# Can't push to a remote repository at GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm using Git-LFS and the message is:

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/13), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.
error: failed to push some refs to 'repoURL'
```

Will I be able to push local commits next month, or should I remove git-lfs?

Comment: Check [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage) article for more info on storage quota and bandwidth quota, also have a look at [this](https://github.com/settings/billing) to check which quota you have exceeded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to buy add more data.
Go to your github profile/settings/billing/
You will see the Git LFS Data section.

You will be charged $2.58 today for 1 additional data pack. Each data pack gives you an additional 50 GB storage, 50 GB/month bandwidth.

Be careful with every push because it counts against the available storage, pushing 2 times the same file of 500MB would be using an entire gigabyte.